# Почему не выполняется скрипт? Новичок

Tags: javascript

Это мой первый урок javascript. Hello выводится при открытии страницы, а скрипт не выполняется. Почему?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Object Oriented Javascript</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  Hello!!!
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var customer = {
      name: "Tom Smith",
      speak: function() {
        return "My name is " + this.name;
      },
      address: {
        street: '123 Main St',
        city: "Pittsburgh",
        state: "PA"
      }
    };
    document.write(customer.speak() + <br/>);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Если скрипт не отрабатывает, проверьте консоль браузера. Вдруг ошибка в коде. Клавиша F12 или через меню браузера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка здесь `document.write(customer.speak() + <br />);`Надо `<br />` взять в кавычки.
Подробнее тут https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write

Answer (score 3):

### Почему не выполняется скрипт?

как и сказал Александр: у вас опечатка.

> Подробнее тут https://learn.javascript.ru/document-write

а ещё тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/write

### как избежать опечаток, рекомендации новичку JavaScript

например

- воспользоваться редактором [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/
- расширение для хрома [user-javascript-and-css](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)
- [web server for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)

### как в гугле искать документацию JavaScript

искать в документации MOZILLA с помощью поисковой системы от гугла так: `MDN [искомый метод]`

```
MDN document.write
MDN insertAdjacentElement
MDN insertAdjacentHTML
MDN insertAdjacentText
MDN innerHTML
```

искать на сайте learn.javascript.ru с помощью поисковой системы от гугла так: `site:learn.javascript.ru [искомая информация]`

```
site:learn.javascript.ru document.write
site:learn.javascript.ru insertAdjacentElement
site:learn.javascript.ru insertAdjacentHTML
site:learn.javascript.ru insertAdjacentText
site:learn.javascript.ru innerHTML
```

### рекомендую

я вам настоятельно рекомендую познакомиться вот с этой троицей

```
let el: HTMLElement

el.insertAdjacentElement
el.insertAdjacentHTML
el.insertAdjacentText
```

небольшой пример:

```js
/**
 * @type {HTMLElement}
 */
let el = document.body
/**
 * @type {HTMLDivElement}
 */
let div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = `i'am div`

el.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', div)
el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<h1>head</h1>')
el.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', '<p>just text<p>')

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} el
 */
function HTML(el) {
    /**
     * @param {TemplateStringsArray} t
     * @param {any[]} s
     */
    function html(t, ...s) {
        el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', String.raw(t, ...s))
    }
    return html
}

let html = HTML(div)

html`
    <br>add some text to <b>div</b>
`

const LI = _str => `<li>${_str}</li>`

html`
    <ul>
        ${[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(LI).join('')}
    </ul>
`
html`
    <ul>
        ${Array.from({ length: 8 }, (v, i) => LI(i)).join('')}
    </ul>
`
```